# Installing GeoServer on https in IIS7?

Tags: geoserver, installation, iis, jetty

I'm on IIS 7, running GeoServer I cannot get GeoServer to work on https and looking for any insight on how to get this to work:

Our website and GeoServer are on same domain
http**s**://mymapapp.com
     http://mymapapp.com:8080/geoserver/

Our website is on https, port 443 w/ certificate installed
GeoServer is on http, port 8080

When a customer views our website they get a insecure content error message because we are pulling tiles from GeoServer over http and not https (http://mymapapp.com:8080/geoserver/)

I'm on IIS 7, running GeoServer through Jetty.

Does anyone know what are steps to configure GeoServer to work on https and still be on the same domain?

Comment: Did you fixed it ? I have the same problem !

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @bugmenot123, they:

> have no idea about Jetty or IIS [but] would probably put a reverse proxy
>   in front of it, so that eg /geoserver/ gets handled by localhost:8080
>   internally. That way you would have just one HTTPS server as
>   "front-end". Quick search suggests that you can configure IIS as
>   reverse proxy.

Answer (score 1):

In IIS, go to URL Rewrite section and set a new rule. You should set a regular expression that includes all http and https requests and then redirect them to http url of the Geoserver.
For example set this regular expression below:

```
^myserver/(.*)
```

And then redirect to a http address like this below:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/{R:1}
```

It worked for me easily.

[image]